# Cardinality of the set of arguments in integration

Tags: integration, continuum-theory

Consider a function $f(x)$ with domain $D_f=\{x\in \mathbb{R} \space|\space 0\le x\le1 \}$

Since $D_f$ is an interval of $\mathbb{R}$, it is an uncountable set and its cardinality is $\aleph_1$ under the axiomatic continuum hypothesis.

Say we want to calculate the integral $\int_{D_f}f(x)dx$. My question is: What is the cardinality of the set of all values of $x$ at which $f$ is evaluated during integration? Considering Riemann's concept of the integral as the summed up area of an infinite number of rectangles, it should be $\aleph_0$, right? (Since even though the number of rectangles goes to $\infty$, it should still be countably infinite)

Answer (score 4):

The phrase "the values at which $f$ is evaluated *during integration*" already suffers from a bit of a misconception. The definition of the definite (Riemann) integral is a *limit* of finite sums. Evaluating an integral therefore doesn't really evaluate $f$ at any points directly: rather, it is the limit of a sequence of mathematical objects, each of which requires the evaluation of $f$ at finitely many points. If one wants to take the union of all these finite sets and say that they are being evaluated "during integration", then the cardinality of such evaluations is indeed $\aleph_0$. But I would recommend instead trying to change intuition away from the idea that an integral is somehow adding up infinitely many things; that's just a motivating heuristic.

Comment: Ok, but what would be the "correct" intuition then? After all, the idea of integration as an infinite summation seems pretty sound to me. (e. g. considering the total work to be the sum of $\aleph_0$ products of a force and an infinitesimal displacement.)

Comment: Also, I'm not sure I understand properly. I mean, if Riemann's definition of the integral holds (which seems to be true in most cases), how can it be just a motivating heuristic? In the limit, the cardinality of the set of summands (not just the cardinality of the unified set of all possible sums) should be $\aleph_0$.

Comment: The Riemann integral is a limit, not a sum. Therefore it has no set of summands at all. If you want to seek a different definition using infinitesimals, go for it. But one can't derive mathematical facts (like cardinality) from intuition.

Comment: I actually want to get away from thinking in infinitesimals because they aren't really defined in regular analysis (notwithstanding their frequent "coloquial" usage e. g. when solving separable ODEs). Consider https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus if you like. There we can find the definition $F(b)-F(a)=\int_a^b f(x)dx=\lim_{\Vert\Delta x_i\Vert\to 0}\sum_{i=1}^n[f(c_i)\Delta x_i]$. Why wouldn't that be a countably infinite sum, given that $\Delta x_i$ must be a nonzero real number and thus fulfill the Archimedean property?

Comment: For clarification: By Archimedean property I mean $\exists n\in\mathbb{N}:n\Delta x_i>(b-a)$?

Comment: (I mean, if that weren't to hold, we'd be back at infinitesimals, right?)